# NullPointerException while Loading and Displaying JSON content into a listview

Tags: android, json

I am attempting to load JSON content into a listview containing image and text but I'm getting a `NullPointerException`' in line 154 i.e `lv1.setAdapter(efficienadapter);` in Actualities.class .

I don't know if its because the `postlist is null or an error in my code.`

someone can help me please

My Actualites class
android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:329)

```
01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:133)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at fr.dtweb.gpf.Actualites.onCreate(Actualites.java:154)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)

01-24 13:03:44.741: E/AndroidRuntime(4357):     ... 18 more
```

Comment: where is line number 154 in Actualites.java

Comment: @ lv1.setAdapter(efficienadapter);

Comment: are you getting PostList size in System.out.println("size: "+PostList.size()); line ?

Comment: yes it return an integer

Comment: wait i'll inbox you the code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to set default value for `isActusAstuce` before using it . if you are accessing it from other application components then make it static as :

```
public static  Boolean isActusAstuce=false;
```

instead of

```
public Boolean isActusAstuce;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that lv1 is null. Some possibilities are:

- There in no view in the layout actualites.xml with the id `list`
- There is a mismatch between the standard `android.R.id.list` and your own 
  `fr.dtweb.gpf.R.id.list`

android id 
xml : `android:id="@android:id/list"`
code : `import android.R`

your own id
xml : `android:id="@+id/list"`
code : `import fr.dtweb.gpf.R`

Comment: the xml is ok i just checked. but for the listview it seems your right